# Comparing "Animal Shelter" on Steam and "Animal Shelter Simulator" on other platforms

Tags: steam, macos, version-differences, animal-shelter

I would like to play ["Animal Shelter" on Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1239320/Animal_Shelter/) but I do not have an appropriate device for playing it since my personal computer is a Mac.  It appears that there is an identical or nearly identical game "[Animal Shelter Simulator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/animal-shelter-simulator/id1593394971)" for mobile platforms and mac.

What is the relationship between these games?  They seem to be different publishers.  I am concerned about playing the "Simulator" version if it's potentially infringing on intellectual property of the original.

In terms of gameplay, are they similar?

Comment: They games look similar, but they do have some differences visually, and I don't mean because of the platform differences.  The mobile game appears to have people in the game (sprites of humans at least), where the Steam game doesn't appear to have that.  Whether or not the mobile game is infringing on intellectual property is up for debate.  I think it could just be pure coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The games have a similar premise, but there are some differences.  The Mac/ios game is a F2P game with advertising.  The steam game is a paid product.  The gameplay has a lot of similarities but some divergent features as noted by Timmy.

In terms of intellectual property, the companies involved are intertwined.  Playway SA and Games Incubator are listed as creators of the Steam version, and Digital Melody the ios/mac version.  All three companies are involved together, with Playway investing in other "Games Incubator" titles.  One developer at Games Incubator tweets about both games.